# Product Collections: Get ALL products even though "Show products that are out of stock" set to NO?

Tags: magento-1.7, product, collection, stock

I’d like to list products using Product Collections that list ALL products regardless is_salable or in_stock are false. Is there a way I can disable all is_salable or in_stock checks for `Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')` ?

Getting the product collection is done using:

```
$selections = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/product_collection')
  ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
  ->addMinimalPrice()
  ->addFinalPrice()
  ->addTaxPercents()
  ->addStoreFilter()
  ->addIdFilter($selection_ids, false)
  ->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

  $selections->load();
```

but because "Show products that are out of stock" ist set to NO it automatically wipes all products that are not in stock.

Is there a way to bypass the "show_out_of_stock" check? Thanks for any assistance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very weird. Can't really tell why, but removing
`->addFinalPrice()` fixed the issue. Obviously addFinalPrice() removes all products that aren't saleable/in stock.

Answer (score 2):

With Magento 1.8, comment *addMinimalPrice* and *addFinalPrice* in *Mage_Catalog_Model_Layer::prepareProductCollection()* to show out of stock products with *Show products that are out of stock* set to NO.